# How to click on a specific button in a popup window in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I'm totally new to this platform and seeking for your help.

I'm working with  a PPC company and I need to automate the add clicking process.

Browser using - Google Chrome
The process need to automate-once click on a advertisement,it loads as a popup.then need to wait for 5Second and click on button to confirm.button is appears in different positions in different adds.

Kindly help me to automate this task.I don't have programming knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we'd need to see some typical HTML/CSS/JS which shows the sort of scenario you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no programming knowledge, you could try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and Python to click the buttons. To use it you need to install selenium by doing `pip install selenium` if you are on Linux. For Windows look at the [instructions for Windows users](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#detailed-instructions-for-windows-users). Then you need to download the [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to connect Selenium to Chrome. For your particular usecase you could have a look a the simple usage example linked above. If you want to understand the script better just change things and look what happens. That's all I can help you without knowing the particular site. But if you have have no programming knowledge at all start first by learning a bit Python, for that there are many sources online, like Youtube, Websites and even interactive courses.